# Using @ with friendly_id rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I want to use '@' before the link in friendly_id
I have username and I am saving username in database with '@' symbol. Its working correctly.
But Friendly_id is showing

```
example.com/username
```

and I want

```
example.com/@username
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

we can do it by overwriting normalize_friendly_id method

```
def normalize_friendly_id(string)
    super.insert(0, '@')
end
```